# Getting the error: Cannot GET / despite linking HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to use host the following js file using nodejs as my first time. The following is the beginning of code to it. I had to use JSDOM since I was trying to use the buttons from the blog.html file in here. The file 'index.html' is present in the folder public and when I run it on terminal, I see the message 'hosting' but it says 'cannot GET /'. Here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const app =express();
app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log('hosting'));
app.use(express.static('public' ));
app.get('./blog.html', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile('blog.html');
}); 

var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const { document } = (new JSDOM('blog.html')).window;
global.document = document;



const postBtn1 = document.getElementById("post-btn1");
const postBtn2 = document.getElementById("post-btn2");
const postBtn3 = document.getElementById("post-btn3");
```

Comment: Try withoud dot => app.get('/blog.html', function(request, response)

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: Try this: response.sendFile('blog.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });

Comment: also didnt work sorry